# ErrorException ReflectionFunction::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel

I have added authentication in my controller but I have got error that parameter 1 expects string array given, still I have not got any string in my function.

Below is my controller code ----------------------------------------------

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
  
    $data = $request -> input();
    $request->session()->put('email', $data['email']);
    echo session('email');
   
}
```

HTML Code --------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<form action="{{ route('users.authenticate') }}" id="authenticationForm" method="post" class="login-form">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" class="form-label" >Email Address </label>
        <input type="email" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="name@example.com"> 
        <span id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1_error" class="error-text"> </span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword1" id="password" class="form-label">Password </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1" placeholder="Passowrd">
        <span id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1_error" class="error-text"> </span>
        
    </div>
    <div class="button-holder">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-property btn-primary" id="Login_button" > Login </button>
        <input type="hidden" id="login-token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

api.php --------------------------------

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/users', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->users();
});



    Route::post('store', [usersController::class,'store']);
    Route::get('index', [usersController::class,'index']);
    Route::post('userLogin',[usersController::class, 'userLogin'])->name('users.userLogin');
    Route::post('authenticate',[usersController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('users.authenticate');
```

web.php -------------------------------

```
Route::post('/store', 'usersController@store');
Route::post('store',[usersController::class, 'store'])->name('users.store');
Route::get('/index', 'usersController@index');
Route::post('/userLogin',[usersController::class, 'login'])->name('users.userLogin');
Route::post('/userLogin', 'usersController@userLogin');
Route::post('authenticate',[usersController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('users.authenticate');
Route::post('authenticate', 'usersController@authenticate');
Route::resource('cities','citiesController');
Route::resource('locations','locationsController');
Route::resource('log','logsController');
Route::resource('properties','propertiesController');
Route::resource('tasks','tasksController');
Route::resource('usersinformation','usersinformationController');
Route::resource('users','usersController');
```

Comment: Please can you add the whole stacktrace for the error.

Comment: (1/1) ErrorException

ReflectionFunction::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
in RouteSignatureParameters.php line 22
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'ReflectionFunction::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given', 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\laravel-project\\property\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteSignatureParameters.php', 22, array('action' => array('middleware' => 'api', 'uses' => array('App\\http\\Controllers\\usersController', 'authenticate'), 'namespace' =>

Comment: This is a routing issue. Have you recently updated your app to Laravel 8? Please can you edit your question and add the code for your routes file to it.

Comment: I have added the web.php and api.php route file section

Comment: You didn't answer my question about. Have you recently updated your app to Laravel 8? Also, is that all the code in your routes files??

Comment: NO, there are other routes as well and my version of Laravel used is Laravel Framework 5.4.36 as of now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind the error was due to an invalid route in web.php

After adding below route it is working like a charm.

```
Route::post('authenticate', [
'as' => 'users.authenticate',
'uses' => 'usersController@authenticate'
```

]);